# getting don't cares when trying to read from sram, scratch or led reg VHDL

Tags: memory, controller, vhdl

I'm trying to implement a memory controller that can read/write to either a sram, scratch register, or led register (basically a scratch reg that blinks a led). I need to use a bidirectional bus, but it outputs an 'X' wherever a 1 should be. This usually happens when you have two different things driving the same signal, but I don't see where that is happening in my code.

```
library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mem_control is 
    port(
  clk              : in    std_logic;
  write_en         : in    std_logic;
  read_en          : in    std_logic;
  bus_address      : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  bus_data         : inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  write_en_sram    : out   std_logic;
  read_en_led      : out   std_logic;
  write_en_led     : out   std_logic;
  write_en_scratch : out   std_logic;
  bus_in_sram      : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  bus_out_sram     : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  bus_in_led       : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  bus_out_led      : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  bus_in_scratch   : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  bus_out_scratch  : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  addr_out         : out   std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
);

end mem_control;

architecture bhv of mem_control is 
--buffer signals
signal bus_out     : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
--processes begin
begin

mem_write : process(clk) is 
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
       if write_en = '1' and read_en ='0' then   --writing logic
         case To_integer(unsigned(bus_address)) is
           when 16#000# to 16#3FF# =>
             write_en_sram <= '1';
             write_en_led <= '0';
             write_en_scratch <= '0';
             bus_out_sram <= bus_data;
             addr_out <= bus_address;
           when 16#400# =>
             write_en_sram <= '0';
             write_en_led <= '1';
             write_en_scratch <= '0';
             bus_out_led <= bus_data;
           when 16#404# =>
             write_en_sram <= '0';
             write_en_led <= '0';
             write_en_scratch <= '1';
             bus_out_scratch <= bus_data;
           when others =>
             null;
           end case;
         end if;
       end if;
end process mem_write;

mem_read : process(clk) is
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
       if read_en = '1' and write_en = '0' then  --reading logic

          case To_integer(unsigned(bus_address)) is
             when 16#000# to 16#3FF# =>
               bus_out <= bus_in_sram;
               read_en_led <= '0';
               addr_out <= bus_address;
             when 16#400# =>
               bus_out <= bus_in_led;
               read_en_led <= '1';

             when 16#404# =>
               bus_out <= bus_in_scratch;
               read_en_led <= '0';

             when others =>
               null;
             end case;
          end if;
        end if;
  end process mem_read;

--led register and tristate buffers  
bus_data <= bus_out when(write_en = '0' and read_en = '1') else (others => 'Z');

end bhv;
```

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve] allowing your problem to be replicated. There's only one driver here on bus_data. What is the associated actual, does it have any drivers and what are any default values?

Comment: Can you post the testbench?

Comment: Your bus enable timing seems to be off... But no way for us to check that without an [mcve].

Comment: `bus_data` is a bidirectional signal. Please make sure you assign 'Z' values to it in your testbench when not actively driving this signal. Btw. 'X' does not mean 'don't care', it means 'unknown' and is usually the result of multiple drivers on one signal.